# Why does mongo think the model is incorrect for the JSON I pass in?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I am trying to store some dates in my Mongodb and I am getting an error when the save is executed

Here is my schema:

```
const pps_Schema = new Schema({

dates:[
    {
        date:[
        {
            beg: {type: Date, required: true},
            end: {type: Date, required: true}
        }
    ]
    }
],
})
module.exports = PPS = mongoose.model('__pps', pps_Schema)
```

Here is the JSON string that I am sending to the save function

```
{
    "dates": [
        {
        "date": [
            {
            "beg": "2019-11-25T10:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2019-11-25T17:00:00.000Z"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the create function that I call.
I have removed parameters that I use for brevity

```
//
// creates, saves and returns a new PPS or returns error
//
createPPS = ( dates ) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{

        var errors = {};

                const newPPS = new PPS({
                    dates: dates
                });

                newPPS.save()
                .then(add => {
                    if(debugThis){
                        console.log(' ');
                        console.log(' created ' + JSON.stringify(add) );
                        console.log(' ');
                    }
                    resolve(add);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    errors.exception = {'save':err};
                    console.log(errors);
                    reject(errors);
                });
    });
};

module.exports = {
    createPPS,
};
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error:

```
[0] ERROR create{"exception":{"save":{"errors":{"dates.0.date.1.beg": {"message":"Path `beg` is required.","name":"ValidatorError","properties": {"message":"Path `beg` is required.","type":"required","path":"beg"},"kind":"required","path":"beg"}},"_message":"__pps validation failed","message":"__pps validation failed: dates.0.date.1.beg: Path `beg` is required.","name":"ValidationError"}}}
```

Here is the output from Postman:

```
{
    "exception": {
        "save": {
            "errors": {
                "dates.0.dateEnd": {
                    "message": "Path `dateEnd` is required.",
                    "name": "ValidatorError",
                    "properties": {
                        "message": "Path `dateEnd` is required.",
                        "type": "required",
                        "path": "dateEnd"
                    },
                    "kind": "required",
                    "path": "dateEnd"
                },
                "dates.1.dateBeg": {
                    "message": "Path `dateBeg` is required.",
                    "name": "ValidatorError",
                    "properties": {
                        "message": "Path `dateBeg` is required.",
                        "type": "required",
                        "path": "dateBeg"
                    },
                    "kind": "required",
                    "path": "dateBeg"
                }
            },
            "_message": "__pps validation failed",
            "message": "__pps validation failed: dates.0.dateEnd: Path `dateEnd` is required., dates.1.dateBeg: Path `dateBeg` is required.",
            "name": "ValidationError"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that Mongoose expects a single schema for all entries in the array. It probably only looks at the first element of each array in the schema. I'm not sure there is a way to specify that an array should have a collection of objects that are schema'ed differently. In fact, that's a very strange way to define this model anyway -- why not have `beg` and `end` exist on the same object, and *not* place that object in an array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/710446/apsillers - can you give an example of what you mean by "exist on the same object" ?

Comment: I mean an object with two properties, like `{ "beg": "...",  "end": "..." }` If you expect there to be always those two properties, why put them in separate objects? Just have one object with two properties. That also means you don't need a surrounding array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/710446/apsillers - putting both into a single object, I get the same result

Comment: Did you change the schema to expect both properties on the same object? Your schema right now doesn't use the `{ end }` object in a way that supplies schematic meaning (i.e., it's not used) so I was suggesting a modified approach to the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok... so it's very good to have code reviews:

```
const pp = require('./pps');
```

should have been :

```
const pps = require('./pps');
```

problem went away as soon as the correct model was loaded.